# I hold a valid F1 visa, but do I need a B1 visa to travel for a conference?

Tags: visas, usa

I currently hold an F1 visa, valid for 5 years.  I am doing a master's program that requires me to go to the US for short periods of time; I complete the course in 2021. 
 I hope to travel to the US for a conference; do I need to apply for a different type of visa?

Comment: Does this answer your question?  https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/95273/currently-hold-an-f1-visa-not-sure-is-valid-but-will-travel-for-an-academic-c?rq=1

Comment: It doesn't seem like the same question, the other question is someone who had quit their US course, this is someone who is still involved in a US course.

Answer (score 1):

You can only enter with the status you have a visa for. In other words, if you have an F-1 visa that allows you to go to the US border and seek admission under F-1 status. F-1 status is only for people studying full-time at a SEVIS-accreddited school in America. To be admitted under F-1 status, you need a valid I-20 from the international students office. You cannot enter under F-1 status just to go to a conference.

If you are studying outside the US, and simply need to visit the US for the conference, you need to enter under B-1 visitor status. That means you need a B-1 or combination B-1/2 visa, unless you are a national of Canada or a Visa Waiver Program member country.